# Bias sample variance proof

Tags: statistics, variance

I am trying to understand the proof of uncorrected (biased) sample variance proof from
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Sample_variance).

The proof is provided as here:
[Proof from wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZelKg.png)

Only I can't understand the last line in the equation:
$$E[ \frac{1}{n} {\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2 ] = \sigma^2}$$

I understand the definition of of sample variance to be $\frac{1}{n} {\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2 }$, where the $\bar X$ is the sample mean, but I am not sure how the above equation can lead to the expected variance.

Answer (score 1):

We are given that each $X_i$ is a random variable with expectation $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. By definition of the variance of a random variable, this translates into $E(X_i-\mu)^2 = \sigma^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So can I interpret as: since $\bar X = \mu$ in the long run, so we can replace the $\bar X$ with $\mu$? If this works, then the second component in the last line of the proof confused me: $E[(\bar X - \mu)^2] = 1/n * \sigma^2$. I wonder why cannot replace the $\bar X$ here with $\mu$?

Comment: @KatherineChen $\bar X$ is close to $\mu$ in the long run, but it still has variability. For a given sample of size $n$ the variance of $\bar X$ is $\sigma^2/n$. This is small, but not zero. In comparison to a single measurement such as $X_i$, there's not much lost in replacing $\mu$ with $\bar X$. But if you're comparing $\bar X$ to $\mu$, as in the calculation of $E(\bar X-\mu)^2$, then replacing $\bar X$ with $\mu$ is too drastic; you'll end up with zero.

Comment: Thank you for providing the intuition behinds the equation! So if we re-write it as: $E[ \frac{1}{n} {\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X + (\bar X - \mu))^2 ]}$, in the long run, wouldn't the difference inside the bracket $(\bar X - \mu)$ accumulated some significant amount and leads to difference with $E[ \frac{1}{n} {\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2 ]}$?

Comment: @KatherineChen The squared difference $(\bar X-\mu)^2$ is $\sigma^2/n$ on average, and when you do $\frac1n\sum(\bar X-\mu)^2$ the result is still $\sigma^2/n$. So  the difference between $E[\frac1n\sum(X_i-\mu)^2]$ and  $E[\frac1n\sum(X_i-\bar X)^2]$ is $\sigma^2/n$. This difference gets smaller as $n$ gets larger. (Not sure if this answers your question.)

Comment: @grandchat Oh wow.. thank you so much! Yes you did answer my question completely. It makes sense that the 1/n part makes the difference in the long run with n grows large. Really appreciate your clear explanation. Thank you!!